# ERROR: query has no destination for result data: Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, loops, insert

I am using `Postgresql11` and a function that works well in a single run fails when I add a LOOP statement with

> "ERROR: query has no destination for result data HINT: If you want to
>   discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead."

The function has VOID as return value, selects data from a source table into a temp table, calculates some data and inserts the result into a target table. The temp table is then dropped and the function ends. I would like to repeat this procedure in defined intervals and have included a LOOP statement. With LOOP it does not insert into the target table and does not actually loop at all.

```
    create function transfer_cs_regular_loop(trading_pair character varying) returns void
        language plpgsql
    as
    $$
    DECLARE
        first_open decimal;
        first_price decimal;
        last_close decimal;
        last_price decimal;
        highest_price decimal;
        lowest_price decimal;
        trade_volume decimal;
        n_trades int;
        start_time bigint;
        last_entry bigint;
        counter int := 0;
        time_frame int := 10;

    BEGIN
        WHILE counter < 100 LOOP
            SELECT  max(token_trades.trade_time) INTO last_entry FROM token_trades WHERE token_trades.trade_symbol = trading_pair;
            RAISE NOTICE 'Latest Entry: %', last_entry;
            start_time = last_entry - (60 * 1000);
            RAISE NOTICE 'Start Time: %', start_time;
            CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS
                SELECT * FROM token_trades where trade_symbol = trading_pair and trade_time > start_time;
            SELECT temp_table.trade_time,temp_table.trade_price INTO first_open, first_price FROM temp_table ORDER BY temp_table.trade_time ASC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
            SELECT temp_table.trade_time,temp_table.trade_price INTO last_close, last_price FROM temp_table ORDER BY temp_table.trade_time DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
            SELECT max(temp_table.trade_price) INTO highest_price FROM temp_table;
            SELECT min(temp_table.trade_price) INTO lowest_price FROM temp_table;
            SELECT INTO trade_volume sum(temp_table.trade_quantity) FROM temp_table;
            SELECT INTO n_trades count(*) FROM temp_table;
            INSERT INTO candlestick_data_5min_test(open, high, low, close, open_time, close_time, volume, number_trades, trading_pair) VALUES (first_price, highest_price, lowest_price, last_price, first_open, last_close, trade_volume, n_trades, trading_pair);
            DROP TABLE temp_table;
            counter := counter + 1;
            SELECT pg_sleep(time_frame);
            RAISE NOTICE '**************************Counter: %', counter;
        END LOOP;

    END;
    $$;
```

Comment: Did you try doing as the error says, that is to use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT` in the sleep part?

Comment: No, I have not tried. The error message does not really indicate which SELECT is affected. The message in pgadmin4 does point to a line which does not have any SELECT statement.

Comment: It probably points to a line in the function, not the whole text. But if you don’t select *into* the result will be a return value and since it’s a loop it doesn’t return anything so it needs to be a perform instead of select

Comment: I believe every SELECT is assigning a value to a variable with INTO. The code works fine without LOOP. But once the LOOP is in the ERROR message pops up. I don't understand what makes the difference?

Comment: Should I use the PERFORM instead of every SELECT?

Comment: The last SELECT is not storing anything anywhere, it's only there to cause a delay. Change that one to PERFORM.

Comment: Ah, ok, did not really consider this one. Will try

Comment: Aye Sami, that did the trick. You are best. This solved the issue. I am new here, how do I vote you up? Thanx, so made my day!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to the last `SELECT` statement in the function. If there is a `SELECT` without `INTO` it will always return results. When there's no `LOOP` this result will be used as the return value of the function (even if it is void).

When you add a `LOOP` there can't be any `SELECT` without `INTO` inside the loop because a single return value would be needed and now there will be many. In this case you need to use `PERFORM` which does exactly the same thing as a `SELECT` but discards the results.

Therefore change the last `SELECT` into a `PERFORM` and the error will go away:

```
PERFORM pg_sleep(time_frame);
```